# Which npm is used for implementing google map in react admin version 3.0.2

Tags: react-admin

I am using react admin version 3.0.2 and  "@fusionworks/ra-google-maps-input": "^0.1.7" for google map implementation .But  it gives error.why?

Comment: Getting  this error - Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(t)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(t)".

Answer (score -1):

I was limited in using ra-google-maps-input, so I'm using google-map-react.

Comment: Please provide more information on why you made your decision.